# Why host OS should install ffmpeg too, after npm installed?

Tags: macos, ffmpeg

I follow this tutorial [ffmpeg](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eaycf5l7GgI&list=PLtWy6rdN1yBntIyLeNo-fCVR6AaK7vdyl&index=11).

you see the `npm install fluent-ffmpeg`, there have installed it by node.

but why it still needs to be installed on host OS?

```
brew install ffmpeg
```

---

I mean whether the package `fluent-ffmpeg` is not enough, what's the function of `ffmpeg` on host OS?

If I use electron develop a macos app, and build it to pkg, when other macos install it, the macos should install `ffmpeg` then can use it?

Answer (score 1):

You are not installing `ffmpeg` when you install `fluent-ffmpeg`. All that `fluent-ffmpeg` does is provide a "pretty" abstraction layer so that you don't have to fight the `ffmpeg` command line.

https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg

> This library abstracts the complex command-line usage of ffmpeg into a fluent, easy to use node.js module. In order to be able to use this module, make sure you have ffmpeg installed on your system (including all necessary encoding libraries like libmp3lame or libx264).

`ffmpeg` is the tool doing all the work and heavy lifting. `fluent-ffmpeg` just gives you an easy to use interface from `node` rather than having to run `ffmpeg` yourself.

If you write a program that uses `ffmpeg` and give it to another user then that user will also need to have `ffmpeg` installed.